# CSS - Change border-color of div within anchor:hover

Tags: css

I have a div contained within an anchor like so:

```
<a class="chk" href="href">
  <div class="chk-div"></div> Text Here
</a>
```

I want it so that when you hover over the `<a>`, the border-color of the child `<div>` changes.  I know you can do it simply for the div like so:

```
.chk-div:hover {
  border-color: green;
}
```

But I want it to change when you hover over the text also

Comment: You need to understand that div is a block element and anchor is an inline element. What you doing is unnatural and unnecessary...
Put a span in the anchor or just style it but itself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Comment: Thanks both, I've changed it to a <span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you're after?

`.chk:hover .chk-div {border: solid 1px green;}`

https://jsfiddle.net/d7tc0sq8/

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="chk" href="href">
  <div class="chk-div">Text Here</div> 
</a>


.chk-div:hover {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="ckk" href="#">
Text Here
</a>

.chk {padding:10px; border:1px solid black;}
.chk:hover{border-color:green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln8wchfa/1/)**

As you are giving border for div, its a block level element, so use it as inline-block or use span like this

```
<a class="chk" href="href">
  <span class="chk-div">Text</span>  Here
</a>
```

css:

```
.chk-div:hover {
  border: 1px solid green;

}
```